# deployment and exposing app on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

On Ubuntu, I used minikube to deploy and expose an app onto kubernetes. I ran into a problem on how I can use and view the app.

I used this [link](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/nodeport) to resolve this issue.

`minikube service --url $SERVICE`

I expect the output to display the app I deployed on kubernetes.

The actual output from google chrome when I click on the link in ubuntu terminal is:

```
This site can’t be reached 
192.168.99.108 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Here is the pod definition:

```
priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-6sw9l
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-6sw9l
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-09-21T22:50:02Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-09-23T22:05:36Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-09-23T22:05:36Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-09-21T22:50:02Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: 
docker://57c0d2fccc9698ace22600f3d3197416324ed3bf570f929562d4669bd018d77f
    image: .../test:latest
    imageID: docker-pullable://.../test@sha256:fc6e42ba94b04cafa64c77b76961243695e03441ce0a54d21f22db99c8fdf7d7
        lastState:
          terminated:
            containerID: docker://e5ed21b41e7075681d6be8b46954e8bb5b2e6be2ef63942951b41176d583f03e
            exitCode: 0
            finishedAt: "2019-09-23T21:44:21Z"
            reason: Completed
            startedAt: "2019-09-23T21:43:40Z"
        name: test
        ready: true
        restartCount: 3
        state:
          running:
            startedAt: "2019-09-23T22:05:28Z"
      hostIP: 10.0.2.15
      phase: Running
      podIP: 172.17.0.9
      qosClass: BestEffort
      startTime: "2019-09-21T22:50:02Z"
```

Here is the service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-21T22:50:13Z"
  labels:
    app: tesb-node
  name: tesb-node
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "51502"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/tesb-node
  uid: d0182ca7-cbd0-4c56-a2b7-a9e6f1c64621
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.99.98.201
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30178
    port: 84
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 84
  selector:
    app: tesb-node
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this command `minikube dashboard` to access k8 dashboard in a web browser?

Comment: What application you want to deploy and expose? Can you add yaml files?

Comment: The app that I want to deploy and expose has vs code (asp.net core)

Comment: Can you tell me if minikube is working on your local pc? Or it's like you are working on a pc/laptop where you have a VM with ubuntu?

Comment: @Martijn data had already been appended on, so I've removed the duplicate appended data

Comment: I have minikube working in my laptop with ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass NodePort number with ip to receive response. Can to try

```
kubectl get service $SERVICE --output='jsonpath="{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}"'
```

to get the port number?

Comment: I got the port number. I used the port number with the cluster ip and the output is: This site can’t be reached ... took too long to respond. Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT     (what else can I do in this case?)

Comment: The output of kubectl get svc is the node port. I used this with cluster ip (http://<cluster ip>.<node port>) in google chrome and the output is: This site can’t be reached10.111.127.243 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention that this app has asp.net core, when I deployed and exposed it to kubernetes. How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your pods up and running? And the ports in the service?

Comment: Pod for this app is up and running. The target port is set though the nodeport is unset.

Comment: Can you share the `pod` and `service` definition?

Comment: What do you mean by pod and service definition?

Comment: Get these details by `kubectl get po -o yaml` and `kubectl get svc -o yaml`

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in your pod definition there is no containerPort in your [container spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster), add it and everything should work.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: How do I get the containerPort? Where do I put the containerPort to make this work?

Comment: You just need to write it to your deployment yaml file.
Add `ports:
        - containerPort: 84` to spec.containers.
containerPort in deployment must be the same as targetPort in services, so it's 84 in your example.